# SwiftUI - Material Components , TextFields

Tags: swiftui, mdc-components, uiviewrepresentable, swiftui-form

I want to use mdc components in my SwiftUI app.
I created a class with protocol `UIViewRepresentable`, but I would like to modify the height to some constant or maybe remove inner padding.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MDCOutlinedTextField {
    let textField = MDCOutlinedTextField()
    
    textField.setOutlineColor(MyColor.greyLightUI, for: .normal)
    textField.setOutlineColor(MyColor.greyLightUI, for: .editing)
    textField.setFloatingLabelColor(MyColor.greyUI, for: .normal)
    textField.setFloatingLabelColor(MyColor.greyUI, for: .editing)
    textField.setNormalLabelColor(MyColor.greyUI, for: .normal)
    textField.setNormalLabelColor(MyColor.greyUI, for: .editing)
    textField.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Normal", size: 14)
    textField.setTextColor(MyColor.darkUI, for: .normal)
    textField.setTextColor(MyColor.darkUI, for: .editing)
    
    textField.keyboardType = self.keyboardType
    
    return textField
}
```